# I got different result for the same function in r

Tags: r

I tried to make my function much more conveient to read. So, instead of repeating my code many times, I used `lapply`. However, I got different result for the same function. My aim is, if I have a large list, for example, `X = (x1, x2,..,x10)`. So instead of writing a long code for `10` elements, I would to write simple code using `lapply`. But I got different result.

Here is my code:

```
    x1 <- rnorm(10,4,2)
x2 <- rnorm(10, 3,3)
x <- list(x1,x2)
w <- c(0.5,0.5)
ll_1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) log(w[[i]] * dnorm(x[[i]],log=F)))
ll_new <- sum(unlist(ll_1))

ll_2 <- sum(log(w[[1]]*dnorm(x1,log=F)+w[[2]]*dnorm(x2,log=F)))


> identical(ll_new ,ll_2)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: In `ll_2` you've got `w[[1]]` and `w[[2]]` inside the `log` function; in `ll_1` it's not.

Comment: Problem is you're comparing two different functions, try `ll_2 <- sum(log(w[[1]]*dnorm(x1,log=F)),log(w[[2]]*dnorm(x2,log=F)))`

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks so much for your comment. I edit it, however, my problem is still arise.

Comment: @Niek thanks so much. the problem is still the same. I think my problem is in the sum.

Comment: Your issue is basically `log(a+b) != log(a) + log(b)`. In `ll_new` you calculate `log(a) + log(b)`, in `ll_2` you have `log(a+b)`, where `a = w[1] * dnorm(x[[1]])` and `b = w[2] * dnorm(x[[2]])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log of sum is not equal to sum of log (`log( a + b ) != log(a) + log(b)`)...

```
x1 <- rnorm(10,4,2)
x2 <- rnorm(10, 3,3)
x <- list(x1,x2)
w <- c(0.5,0.5)
ll_1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) log(w[[i]] * dnorm(x[[i]],log=F)))
ll_new <- sum(unlist(ll_1))

ll_2 <- sum(log(w[[1]]*dnorm(x[[1]],log=F))+log(w[[2]]*dnorm(x[[2]],log=F)))

identical(ll_new ,ll_2)
[1] TRUE
```